# ASP.NET MVC C# show image from text url in database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database

I have been searching for an answer for this but can't seam to find one.

```
<div class="text-center">
    <img src="@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Image)" class="img-thumbnail">
</div>
```

This is the section I'm using. Basically I'm inputting the url as text into the database and when I use the above code (in the details page) it shows the image in Internet Explorer, but not in Chrome.

I'm VERY new to this so I'm unsure how to do this.

Thanks

Comment: You need to show what the value of `Image` is and the actual html that is being generated

Comment: The answers provided by Tim and CodingYoshi should work. I don't know of the issue you mention when it comes to chrome. What you can do though is  to inspect the web page by Pressing **F12**. Then look at the image link if it it correct.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work. I have inspected the web page and yes they url is there as <img src="url"> yet it doesn't show the image.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Url.Content` as shown below since `Model.Image` has the URL:

```
<div class="text-center">
    <img src="@Url.Content(Model.Image)" class="img-thumbnail">
</div>
```

Comment: @pulpetti I have never come across such issue. All it does is render a url. What happens if you inspect the element, what is the URL that is rendered.

Comment: When i inspect i can find the URL but it doesn't show the image (Only shows in IE)